# How one makes a nice approximation using Taylor series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Approximations of expressions like $2^{0.6}$ , or $3^{0.7}$ . For firrst one i know binomial expansion can help with x very less we need but is it better to do taylor expansion around √2 than binomially expansion if we just need upto three decimal places ? ( I know the log values needed for taylor expansion so basically is it better to do taylor expansion around √2 or some better value , or binomial is best , if we meed upto 3 decimal places)

Comment: You are looking for "binomial series", which is the Taylor series of $(1 + x)^k$. Multiply by a suitable constant to change the $1$ into something else.

Comment: How about taylor expansion around √2 ?

Comment: Why $\sqrt{2}$? It is better to minimise the value of $x$ to speed up the rate of convergence.

Comment: I need upto three decimal places the closest values , so can taylor around √2 not help ?

Comment: Yes it can help, but it depends on what you are trying to calculate. If you can better explain your thought process in your question, your question is less likely to get closed.

Comment: Yeah so then Sir can u just share how it helps upto three decimal places in a solution , and is it better than binomial expansion, the taylor series?

Comment: You need to edit your question first. If you haven't already, please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Now is it all gud Sir?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122377/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-waybig).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $2^{0.6}$ as $\exp(0.6 \ln 2)$ where $\exp(x) = e^x$, where you know $\ln 2$ to three decimal places.

Then since $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + O(x^5)$, the maximum Lagrange remainder is the next term, thus $\frac{(0.6 \ln 2)^n}{n!} > 0.001$ for any power of $n$. Some trial and error gives $n  > 4$, so we need the $x^5$ term as well:

$$2^{0.6} \approx1 + 0.6 \ln 2 + \frac{1}{2!}(0.6 \ln 2)^2 + \frac{1}{3!}(0.6 \ln 2)^3 + \frac{1}{4!}(0.6 \ln 2)^4 + \frac{1}{5!}(0.6 \ln 2)^5$$

and the approximation with $\ln 2 \approx 0.693$ gives $1.51558$, whereas the actual value of $2^{0.6}$ is around $1.51572$, an absolute error of around $1.4 \times 10^{-4}$, and a relative error of $9.3 \times 10^{-5}$.

Comment: It does not make much sense to add that $O(x^6)$ to the approximation of $2^{0.6}$. What is $x$?

Comment: $x = 0.6 \ln2$.

Comment: But then $O((0.6\ln 2)^6) =O(1)$. Since you write $\approx$, I would just terminate the series after the fifth power.

Comment: I thought I was still writing the Taylor series of $e^x$ there, so thanks for catching my mistake. I've replaced the O-notation with $\cdots$.

Comment: Nice way Sir ty :)

Answer (score 3):

Newton's binomial series is:

$$(1+x)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha x + \frac12 \alpha (\alpha-1)x^2+ \frac16 \alpha (\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)x^3+... \tag{1}$$

which is a Taylor expansion valid for $|x|<1$.

Therefore, one could think that $2^{0.6}=(1+x)^{\alpha}$ with $x=1$ is impossible, **but** "everything can happen on the circle of convergence $|z|=1$ and it happens that for $z=1$, relationship (1) gives a convergent series:

$$2^{0.6}=(1+1)^{0.6}=1+0.6 - \frac12  0.6 \times 0.4 + \frac16 0.6 \times 0.4 \times 1.4 +... \tag{1}$$

But its convergence is very slow as one can expect on the circle of convergence : one need 23 terms to have an error less thatn $10^{-3}$.

**Two alternative methods:**

a) Compute its inverse $1/2^{0.6}$ in the following way and inverse the result by hand computation.

$$\left(\frac12\right)^{0.6}=\left(1-\frac12\right)^{0.6}=...$$

for which we can use expansion (1) with $x=-\frac12$.

b) One could also compute in a separate way

$$\begin{cases}\left(\dfrac43\right)^{0.6}&=&\left(1+\dfrac13\right)^{0.6}&=&1+0.6 \times \dfrac13 - \frac12 0.6 \times 0.4 \left(\dfrac13\right)^2+...\\
\left(\dfrac23\right)^{0.6}&=&\left(1-\dfrac13\right)^{0.6}&=&1-0.6 \times \dfrac13 - \frac12 0.6 \times 0.4 \left(\dfrac13\right)^2+...
\end{cases}$$

What for? Plainly because the quotient of these results gives $2^{0.6}$...

(Both series have a rather good convergence speed. Moreover, they have the same terms, either with the same sign, or its opposite).

Comment: Agree Sir , so how would be the idea of doing taylor expansion centered around √2 ? For 2^0.5 case

Comment: @JeanMarie See the chat thread for what the OP means.

Comment: @WayBig The problem is that you can't use a linear approximation based on just one point. The derivative is constantly changing, and so the linear approximation will be inaccurate if you don't have other data points. You would need to use more subintervals, such as $2^{0.52}, 2^{0.54}, 2^{0.56}, 2^{0.58}$ like in the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).

Comment: Hmm now i see , i got your pt Toby Mak Sir and ty Jean Marie Sir too for more clarifying

Comment: So ig best is the method Jean Marie Sir suggested right ?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I have almost completly re-written my answer.